# Laravel ExceptionHandler not loading

Tags: laravel, exception, singleton, render, handler

I needed to catch and handle some exceptions and while I tried to add them to `Handler.php` file I noticed that the file `/app/Exceptions/Handler.php` is not loaded.

Instead the file `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php` is loaded.

Also the file: `/bootstrap/app.php` already has the correct path defined:

```
$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    App\Exceptions\Handler::class
);
```

I tested first by trying to `"dd('TEST')"` (inside `/app/Exceptions/Handler.php` file, and nothing happened).
Then I moved the `"dd('TEST')"` inside `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php` and it appeared on screen, so that's how I know that's the file which is loaded.

Bellow is the function `render()` where I try to catch the exception, but unfortunately, because the file `Handler.php` is not loaded then function `render()` is never called and `dd($exception)` doesn't run.

[image]

Any help is much appreciated. 
Thank you!

Comment: Your configuration seems fine. Could you show how you throw an exception and where you expect to catch it?

Comment: Hello @PtrTon, I have updated the post with `render()` function (which is never called and not showing on screen because instead the one from `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php` is called (I tried by adding a `dd($exception)` there and it is showing on screen.